# How to create an ASP.NET Core ViewResult in a class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In my ASP.NET Core website, I have a class library which does some boring logic but finally returns either:

- `new RedirectResult("-some url");`
- `new ViewResult(....)`

now I'm not sure how I can pass a model to the `ViewResult`?

I tried this:

```
var viewResult = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "MarketingPreferences",
};

viewResult.ViewData.Model = myModel; // Exception is thrown :(
```

but the `viewData` property is null.

So then I thought: just create it, right?

`viewResult.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(..)` but I don't know what to pass into that :(

There are the two options:

- `public ViewDataDictionary(ViewDataDictionary source);`
- `public ViewDataDictionary(IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, ModelStateDictionary modelState);`

and I don't have an existing `ViewDataDictionary` in the first option ...

and for the second .. i have no idea what an `IModelMetadataProvider`  is?

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Or use the controller helper method `View("name", model);`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - I'm not in a Controller class (ie. this library class hasn't inherited from `ControllerBase` or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass model to the `ViewResult`, You can follow this code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

public class Test
    {
        Stu stu = new Stu()
        {
            Name = "Jack"
        };


        public ViewResult test()
        {
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Stu>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());
            viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Stu>(viewData, stu);

            ViewResult viewresult = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewData = viewData
            };


            return viewresult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: nope - that doesn't compile. Does this require a specific namespace or nuget package?

Comment: No, It doesn't require any nuget pakage, It needs `using System.Web.Mvc;`, Check the answer i updated, I just hard code here.

Comment: And this works with .NET core 3.1? (aka. `netcoreapp3.1`)

Comment: You don't use it in class library?

Comment: I don't think System.web.mvc exists in .net core 3.1 .... that's the old full-framework 4.x stuff?

Comment: HI@Learning MongoDB, I have update my answer to asp.net core.

Comment: Yep! ta - that's exactly what I ended up finding and using today. Perfect!

Comment: Also - you don't need the 2nd viewModel creation. just the first one.

Comment: yes, I know, I just want to show more details .